# How to repeatly post and receive data but make app stil responseable EDITED

Tags: java, php, android, raspberry-pi, android-volley

I need to repeatly post data to php and get them back but make app still responseable.My code works but after some time(about 1 minute) my app stop responding.

At first i tried to add POST() function to onResponse() function (onRespose call POST function which make new request and again and again) but this freeze my app so i add timer which call function every 1 milisecond

.

.

.

After edit my app works same as before (works only if connected to pc) if I open app and my phone is not connected to pc, app fall after 1 minute so i still have same problem as at beginning. If someone find mistake please tell me where.
.

.

.

My edited code:

.

MainActivity.java

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Sync.CallBack {

    final String URL = "***";
    final String KEY = "***";
    Data data;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        data = new Data();
        data.key = KEY;
        data.pressed = "0";
        textView = findViewById(R.id.status);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StartSync();

    }

    public void btnClick(View view) {
        data.pressed = "1";

    }


    @Override
    public void onCallBack(String data) {
        textView.setText(data);
    }
    public void StartSync(){
        Sync thread = new Sync(this,data,this);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Sync.java

```java
public class Sync extends Thread{
    private Context context;
    boolean wait = false;
    final String URL = "***";
    public CallBack listener;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    public Data data;

    public interface CallBack{
        void onCallBack(String data);
    }
    public Sync(CallBack listener,Data data,Context context){
        this.listener = listener;
        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    };

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            wait = true;
            POST();
            while(wait){}
        }
    }
    private void POST(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        wait = false;
                        listener.onCallBack(response);

                    }
                },new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                wait = false;
                Toast.makeText(context,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        ){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("key",data.key);
                params.put("pressed",data.pressed);
                if(data.pressed == "1"){
                    data.pressed = "0";
                }
                return params;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
}
```

Data.java

```java
public class Data {
    String pressed = "0";
    String key = "";
}
```

Comment: There's an `AsyncTask` class which will do operations on background without blocking the UI thread. You can refer [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)

Comment: I need to repeatly send fresh data and get data back to print them on screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I can give you an Example how to realize that, but you really need to study the things I will use.

Creating a thread to send and receive Data

```java
 public class myReceiveThread extends Thread{
        public gotNewData listener;

        //Create an interface to pass data to Activity
        public interface gotNewData(){
            void gotNewDataToDisplay(String data); //or int or data or what ever.
        }

        //CTor
        public myThread(gotNewData listener){
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){
            while(myAppisRunnung == true){



                //Receive Data
                listener.gotNewDataToDisplay("New Data");
            }
        }
        }
```

In main Activity:

```java
//In Main activity
public class MainActivity extends AppCompactActiity implements gotNewData{

//what ever

public void startThread(){
     myReceiveThread thread = new myReceiveThread(this);
     thread.start();
}

@Override
public void gotNewDataToDisplay(String data){
    someTextView.setText(data);
  }
}
```

Create a sending thread

```java
public class mySendingThread extends Thread{
private BlockingQueue<String> toSendMessages= new BlockingQueue<>();

Public mySendingThread (BlockingQueue<String> toSendMessages){
this.toSendMessages = toSendMessages;
}

@Override
        public void run(){
            while(myAppisRunnung == true){
             String message= toSendMessages.take();
//Send message
}
}
}
```

In mainActivity

```java
public void startSendThread(){
     mySendingThread threadSend = new mySendingThread(MessageQueue);
     thread.start();
}
```

In mainActivity you need a `BlockingQueue<String> MessageQueue`
And can add every message you want.

Comment: I need to send data which are in main thread and get them back but your code which you write will only receive data.

Comment: @MenTom_CZ you question is really not that good explained. I can just guess what you really what. What data do you want to send to php or where does it come from exactly? Is it a user input or what?

Comment: I need to post key to php to confirm device and send some string which can be changed

Comment: @MenTom_CZ then create 2 threads one sending and one receiving and pass the data to send to the sending one.